# Vuejs onclick on v-for in array whith 2 of each items, makes the action on both items rather than the clicked one

Tags: onclick, vuejs3, target, v-for

I'm trying to learn Vuejs3,making a simple memory game.
I pick the list of cards and make an array of objects [screen 2 cards flipped on click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcZo5.png)with 2 times each item for making the pairs to find. (rather than duplicating each card on my data list of cards).
The problem: when I click on the card to flip, it flips the 2 of the same rather than one.[console log of v-for array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV2Kd.png)

I'd like each click to turn only one image from the pair of images.
The only solution that has worked is to put 2 times each item in my data file.
Any ideas? Thanks

method who flips card

```
methods: {
// flip 2 cards and compare them
flipCard(card) {
console.log("flip called");
card.isFlipped = true;
this.pairs.push(card);
if (this.pairs.length == 2) {
console.log(this.pairs\[0\].image, this.pairs\[1\].image);
this.compare(this.pairs\[0\].image, this.pairs\[1\].image);
}
},
```

shuffle cards and push 2 times each card into an array

```
created() {
this.allCards.map((item)=\> {
this.selection.push(item, item);
})
this.selection = this.shuffle(this.selection);
console.log(this.selection);

    this.selection.forEach((card) => {
      card.isFlipped = false;
    });

},
```

template:

```
<template>
  <div class="cardwrap row row-cols-6 row-cols-md-8 g-3">
    <div class="card"  v-for="(card, index) in selection" :key="card[index]">
      <img @click="flipCard(card, card[index])"
        :src="
          card.isFlipped
            ? '../assets/animals/' + card.image
            : '../assets/square.jpg'
        "
        :alt="card.id"
      />
    </div>
```

Comment: I think your problem is because you assign the card to the key, so you might end up with two times the same key for the matching pair. Maybe the `:key="index"` would be enough.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I tried but this doesn't work neither :-/

Comment: How is your `selection`  looking like, e.g. how do you add the pairs to it. JavaScript uses references, so if you just add the same object to the array twice, it will just create two references to the same object. If you change the state on one, it also changes the state on the other. Maybe just cloning it with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` would do the trick.

Comment: can't edit anymore, but this is the more modern way to create a copy: `const copy = Object.assign({}, obj);`